# PayPal recurring payments are in pending state

Tags: civicontribute, paypal

How do I get PayPal Express recurring payments to be recorded correctly? They are in pending mode. No error in ConfigAndLog that corresponds to the processing time. It uses PayPal Express, there is no email configured (which seems to be the most common response to this error). There is a user name + signature option.

Non-recurring payments are going through OK. No details recorded against the recurring ones.

CiviCRM 5.14.0

[PxPay Recur Payment gets stuck in pending mode](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26082/pxpay-recur-payment-gets-stuck-in-pending-mode)
[Paypal payments - Pending (Incomplete Transaction)](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11028/paypal-payments-pending-incomplete-transaction)

Comment: Was it working before and suddenly stopped?

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, PayPal Express and PayPal Payments Pro have always conflicted with Civi.  PayPal Standard works fine for both recurring and one-time payments, but the other two options do not work for recurring payments.  My organization went back and forth with PayPal over this issue for months.  Then we tried to fix it on our end with zero positive results.  We finally concluded  based on what others said in this forum that other than PayPal Standard, most PayPal options are not compatible with Civi.  We now take our credit card payments with iATS, which is specifically designed to work with Civi and also have the option of using PayPal Standard if the user prefers it.

Comment: ^Agreed 100%. Experienced same situation. Save the hassle and go with any other supported payment processor other than paypal. Other reccomendation is using Stripe and authorize.net which have worked well for me.

Comment: It uses the eway credit card gateway. This is how recurring for PayPal came to be, turn on recurring for the credit card gateway and it is on for both payment methods. I guess I'll use some javascript to hide recurring if PayPal is selected.

Answer (score 0):

There was a patch release for 5.14 (5.14.2 is the latest I think - or 5.15.0 has the fix) that may relate

Comment: I tried 5.15.0 but it still has 'no payments found for this record'.